# Swagger UI is blank because of Content-Security-Policy

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I am trying to fix `swagger UI` with issue Content-Security-Policy. I am looking into a way to add a header or `Springfox` config option to fix the issue.

It is not able to load the UI and `v2/api-doc` is working fine.

Please suggest me a way to fix the issue.

Comment: Have you found solution that how we can override this swagger ui is blank due to CSP?

Comment: Yes, it was blocked by an internal filter not to support the Content-Security. I have made it to allow it again.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is due to fastify helmet for me.

```
import headers from "fastify-helmet";
```

Replacing the following in main.ts

```
app.register(headers)'
```

with

```
app.register(helmet, {
    contentSecurityPolicy: {
      directives: {
        defaultSrc: [`'self'`],
        styleSrc: [`'self'`, `'unsafe-inline'`],
        imgSrc: [`'self'`, 'data:', 'validator.swagger.io'],
        scriptSrc: [`'self'`, `https: 'unsafe-inline'`],
      },
    },
  })
```

resolved the issue:

Answer (score 0):

Adding `staticCSP: true` worked for me:

```
server.register(fastifySwagger, {
    exposeRoute: true,
    routePrefix: '/documentation',
    staticCSP: true,
    swagger: {
        info: {
            title: 'whatever',
            description: 'something',
            version: '1.0.0'
        },
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling upon this question now, the answer would be to update your swagger ui version (or the library that uses it) to use Swagger-ui>4.8.1.

Versions lower than that have inline scripts and inline styles that hinder Content Security Policy settings. Issue discussed here
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3370

The fix was introduced here
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/pull/7905

Which ties with swagger-ui 4.8.1 and above.